# How to set twistd.py ILogObserver when using IPlugin?

Tags: python, logging, twisted, twistd

I want to redirect twistd.py's logging to python's logging. When starting a `.tac` file normally I can easily do this:

```
from twisted.python.log import PythonLoggingObserver, ILogObserver
from twisted.application import service

application = service.Application("FooApp")
application.setComponent(ILogObserver, PythonLoggingObserver().emit)
```

However, I don't seem to have an `Application` when writing an `IPlugin`. Instead I just have a class that implements `IServiceMaker` and `IPlugin`, where `makeService` returns a `service.Service`. How can I set this log observer?

Note that I don't just want to add a python logging observer, I want to *redirect* twistd's logging so that it only goes through python's built-in logging system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at twistd's `--logger` parameter:

```
# mylogger.py
from twisted.python import log

def logger():
    return log.PythonLoggingObserver().emit
```

and then invoke twistd: `twistd --logger=mylogger.logger`.

Comment: Seems to work - I had forgotten to setup python logging before when I said it didn't. Thanks!